# MATCH in mysql takes only a single column.

Tags: php, mysql

```
$tex = $_GET['searchMe'];
$query = $Config::$con->query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('".$tex."')");
```

MATCH only takes a single column , either title or description. 
If i add both of the column names in it, i'll get null results when i fetch it.

*NOTE: I've already made both of my columns as FULLTEXT.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I see an opening to SQL injection here.

Comment: You use '&&' and Operator then You use two where coditin

Comment: I want the query to search both title and description columns instead of a single one.

Comment: @AngnimaSherpa Your solution in below Please Check Your solution and tell me Its work or not

Comment: Did you try to use `AGAINST('".$tex." ".$tex."')`

Answer (score 0):

You write a query Look Like this

```
$tex = $_GET['searchMe'];
$query = $Config::$con->query("SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE title = '$tex' && description ='$tex'");
```

Comment: nope! i'm making a search engine for my site. So i'll have to use MATCH & AGAINST to get the results when you search.

Comment: @AngnimaSherpa YOu making which type of search Page search Ya database search any attribute?

Comment: @AngnimaSherpa If You search any database attribute my method is exactly work